# How can I automatically encrypt all file extensions using my batchtool?

Tags: batch-file

I currently have this code I use to encrypt and decrypt files on my disk, but it checks for specific file extensions only, but I want it to encrypt every single file extension. Here is the code I currently have:

```
:1layer
echo Encrypting disk, this may take a while.
set ForLoopFile=%VaultPath%
FOR /f %%G IN ('dir /s /b /a-d %ForLoopFile%') DO (call :Encrypt %%G)
if %layer%==2 goto :2layer
goto :actionask

:Encrypt
set targetFile=%1
set outputFile=%targetFile:txt=txt.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:dll=dll.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:ini=ini.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:exe=exe.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:zip=zip.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:rar=rar.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:png=png.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:jpg=jpg.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:ico=ico.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:gif=gif.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:mp4=mp4.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:m4v=m4v.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:.py=.py.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:asc=asc.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:vbs=vbs.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:bat=bat.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:ovpn=ovpn.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
del /f %targetFile%
exit /b
```

See, I have to change the target extension file for the extensionsI want to check for, but does anyone know how I can make it encrypt every single file, no matter the extension?

If anyone can help me, I'd greatly appreciate it.

I have no idea on how to do this, all I tried was checking for file extensions manually, but this is limitted to the ones I specify, I want every file extension to get encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /s /b /a-d %ForLoopFile%') DO if /i "%%~xG" neq ".aes" (call :Encrypt "%%G")

...

:Encrypt
aes -e %encryptionKey% "%~1" "%~1.aes" >NUL
del /f "%~1"
goto :eof
```

*should* accomplish this ***Note: untried***

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

The modification to the `for` line:
"delims=" to assign the entirety of the filenames to `%%G`, else only the first token will be assigned (see `for/?` from the prompt for docco.
`if /i` - only if (case-insensitive)
"%%~xG" neq ".aes" - the current file extension is **N**ot **EQ**ual to `.aes`
"%%G" - entire filename is one parameter

This *should* skip `.aes` files so that you dont get `.aes.aes.aes.aes` as the procedure is repeated.

The `:encrypt` subroutine:
apply `aes` to the first parameter delivered to the routine (`%1`) stripped of the enclosing quotes (`%~1`); simply add `.aes` to the string for destination file.
then delete the file

This *should* allow filenames including spaces to be processed.

**Note**
add `echo`  before the `aes` and `del` and remove the `>nul` to produce a tester version which will simply show the proposed actions on the console.

***Note: untried***

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

--- Decrypt version (Theoretical)

FOR /f "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /s /b /a-d %ForLoopFile%.aes') DO (call :Decrypt "%%G")

(Allows filenames containing spaces, and selects only files type `*.aes`)

```
:Decrypt
aes -d %encryptionKey% "%~1" "%~dpn1" >NUL
del /f "%~1"
goto :eof
```

(Still theoretical)

decrypts to the **D**rive **P**ath **N**ame of the **1**st parameter.

Note:
Since `"%~1"` is deleted automatically by this code, it would be advisable to gate the `delete` so that any error bypasses the delete. **Logically**, this should be

```
if not errorlevel 1 del /f "%~1"
```

But I am unfamiliar with how `aes` works.

Another way would be

```
if exist "%~1.aes" del /f "%~1"
```

And possibly it would be advisable to use

```
:Decrypt
if exist "%~dpn1" echo Error - "%~dpn1" already exists&goto :eof
aes -d %encryptionKey% "%~1" "%~dpn1" >NUL
del /f "%~1"
goto :eof
```

Comment: This works. Can you help me with the decrypt step? here is the code I have:

Comment: I'll create an answer for my own question with the code.

Comment: Why are you putting a .aes after %ForLoopFile% (FOR /f "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /s /b /a-d %ForLoopFile%.aes') DO (call :Decrypt "%%G")) ForLoopFile is the directory where the files need to get encrypted

Comment: Hmm - well, `forloopFILE` would seem to me to be a filename, not a directoryname. If it's a directoryname, you'd need `%forloopfile%\*.aes` to select all of the `.aes` files. I assume that directorynames do not include a terminal backslash - it makes it easier to mix-and-match than if the backslash is included. I often sermonise on SO about this.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947/magoo

```
FOR /f %%G IN ('dir /s /b /a-d %ForLoopFile%') DO (call :Decrypt %%G)    

:Decrypt
    set targetFile=%1
    set outputFile=%targetFile:txt.aes=txt%
    aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
    set outputFile=%targetFile:dll.aes=dll%
    aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
    set outputFile=%targetFile:ini.aes=ini%
    aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
    set outputFile=%targetFile:exe.aes=exe%
    aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
    set outputFile=%targetFile:zip.aes=zip%
    aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
    set outputFile=%targetFile:rar.aes=rar%
    aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
    set outputFile=%targetFile:png.aes=png%
    aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
    set outputFile=%targetFile:jpg.aes=jpg%
    aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
    set outputFile=%targetFile:ico.aes=ico%
    aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
    set outputFile=%targetFile:gif.aes=gif%
    aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
    set outputFile=%targetFile:mp4.aes=mp4%
    aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
    set outputFile=%targetFile:m4v.aes=m4v%
    aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
    set outputFile=%targetFile:.py.aes=.py%
    aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
    set outputFile=%targetFile:asc.aes=asc%
    aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
    set outputFile=%targetFile:vbs.aes=vbs%
    aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
    set outputFile=%targetFile:bat.aes=bat%
    aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
    set outputFile=%targetFile:ovpn.aes=ovpn%
    aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
    del /f %targetFile%
    exit /b
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947/magoo

Answer (score 0):

Here is my full code:

```
@echo off
color a
title DiskTool - %time%
set VaultPath=\Documents\
set VaultName=Documents
set encryptionKey=133521

:login
cls
echo    ___  _     __  ______          __
echo   / _ \(_)__ / /_/_  __/__  ___  / /
echo  / // / (_- /  '_// / / _ \/ _ \/ / 
echo /____/_/___/_/\_\/_/  \___/\___/_/  v1.1
echo.
echo Welcome to DiskTool, type "help" to view all commands.
echo.
:actionask
set/p "action=> "
set result=true
if %action%==encrypt call :InitForEncrypt
if %action%==decrypt call :InitForDecrypt
if %action%==newkey call :NewKey
if %action%==help call :Help
if %action%==clear goto :login
if %action%==exit exit

echo Command "%action%" not recognised, type "help" to view all commands.
goto :actionask

:GetPass
echo Enter your decryption key to decrypt this disk.
set /p "pass=> "
if NOT %pass%==password goto :Fail
exit /b

:InitForEncrypt
echo Use layer 1 encryption (1) or 2 layer encryption (2)?
set/p "layer=> "
if %layer%==1 goto :1layer
if %layer%==2 goto :1layer
echo Invalid choice.
goto :InitForEncrypt

:1layer
echo Encrypting disk, this may take a while.
set ForLoopFile=%VaultPath%
FOR /f %%G IN ('dir /s /b /a-d %ForLoopFile%') DO (call :Encrypt %%G)
if %layer%==2 goto :2layer
goto :actionask

:2layer
7z a %VaultName%.7z -pjX2wp%85XBOgVO#hatNm -mhe \Documents\ >NUL
rmdir %VaultPath% /q /s
goto :actionask

:InitForDecrypt
call :GetPass
echo Decrypting disk, this may take a while.
if exist %VaultName%.7z 7z x %VaultName%.7z -pjX2wp%85XBOgVO#hatNm >NUL
del /q %VaultName%.7z
:1layerd
set ForLoopFile=%VaultPath%
FOR /f %%G IN ('dir /s /b /a-d %ForLoopFile%') DO (call :Decrypt %%G)
goto :actionask

:Encrypt
set targetFile=%1
set outputFile=%targetFile:txt=txt.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:dll=dll.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:ini=ini.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:exe=exe.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:zip=zip.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:rar=rar.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:png=png.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:jpg=jpg.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:ico=ico.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:gif=gif.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:mp4=mp4.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:m4v=m4v.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:.py=.py.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:asc=asc.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:vbs=vbs.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:bat=bat.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:ovpn=ovpn.aes%
aes -e %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
del /f %targetFile%
exit /b

:Decrypt
set targetFile=%1
set outputFile=%targetFile:txt.aes=txt%
aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:dll.aes=dll%
aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:ini.aes=ini%
aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:exe.aes=exe%
aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:zip.aes=zip%
aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:rar.aes=rar%
aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:png.aes=png%
aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:jpg.aes=jpg%
aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:ico.aes=ico%
aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:gif.aes=gif%
aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:mp4.aes=mp4%
aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:m4v.aes=m4v%
aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:.py.aes=.py%
aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:asc.aes=asc%
aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:vbs.aes=vbs%
aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:bat.aes=bat%
aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
set outputFile=%targetFile:ovpn.aes=ovpn%
aes -d %encryptionKey% %targetFile% %outputFile% >NUL
del /f %targetFile%
exit /b

:Fail
echo Incorrect password, please try again.
goto GetPass

:newkeyfail
echo Can't create new keys when files are encrypted.
goto :actionask

:NewKey
if exist %VaultName%.7z goto :newkeyfail
echo Enter Key Name:
set/p "KeyName=> "
echo Enter Key Content:
set/p "KeyContent=> "
echo %KeyContent% > "%VaultPath%Keys\%KeyName%.txt" >NUL
echo Created %KeyName%.txt
goto :actionask

:Help
echo encrypt - Encrypts files stored in %VaultPath%
echo decrypt - Decrypts all files when password is correct.
echo newkey - Create a new text key in %VaultPath%Keys\.
echo help - displays this command.
echo clear - clears the console.
goto :actionask
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947/magoo